# Real Uploader does not resize images

Tags: javascript, html, image-resizing

I would like to use Real Uploader to resize images before uploading them to the server.

So far everything seems to work just fine, except for the resizing of the images before upload.
I do use Django for server side, but I don't think that should be a problem. Images can be uploaded, but they are simply too big to be handled by the server.

I have tested this on Chrome and Firefox.

The way I have implemented it so far:

```
<head>
    <script src="{% static "js/realuploader-min.js" %}"></script>
    <link href="{% static 'css/realuploader/classic.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Page title</h1>
    <div id="targetElement"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var uploader = new RealUploader("#targetElement",
        {
            url: "{% url "gallery:upload_image" object.pk %}",
            accept: ["image/*"],
            language: "nl_NL",
            resizeImage: {
                maxWidth: 100,
                maxHeight: 200,
                scaleMethod: 3
            },
            previews: false
        }
    );
    </script>    
</body>
```

This all seems simple enough, so I am probably missing something very simple here.
I hope someone can help me out.

## Update 1

I have just found something else:
When I upload the files it shows an error message: `SyntaxError: Unexpected`
The files are still uploaded to the server, though.

Comment: Please re-download the free version. It might be because it was outdated-- the author